# Derivation of binomial coefficient from second order difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I am looking at this [paper](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/weitzman/files/recombinant_growth.pdf) and I am trying to derive Eq. 1 from Eq. 2. It is said that for second order difference equation of the form, 
$$N(t+1)-N(t)=\alpha\Big[C_2(N(t))-C_2(N(t-1))\Big]$$
the solution is,
$$C_2(N)=\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$$
which is equivalent of saying, 
$$\frac{N(N-1)}{2}\equiv\binom{N}{2}$$
for $N\geqslant2$. I wonder how to derive the solution $C_2(N)$ from the second order difference equation? Is this something known in literature that one can derive binomial coefficients from difference equations?

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading the paper. It doesn't derive the binomial coefficients from the difference equation. It introduces the binomial coefficients in equation $(1)$ as the number of pairs, and then *defines* a “binary recombinant expansion process” as one which involves these binomial coefficients in a certain way as in equation $(2)$.

Comment: That's my exact question, how do you get the (1) from (2)?

Comment: @William: You don't. As I said, you're misreading the paper. It doesn't get $(1)$ from $(2)$. You can't, since $(1)$ is just a definition.